# ArcGIS ModelBuilder pass arcpy.SetParameterAsText as input to next tool

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, parameters

I am trying to build a model which uses two simple scripts, Script A and Script B. I want to use arcpy.SetParameterAsText to set an output in script A, which is then used as an input in script B. In the screenshot the output is datetime. But for some reason script B is not executing.

[image]

EDIT:

Script B will run on itws own, but it won't display the parameter passed by script A

Script A

[image]

Script B:

[image]

Comment: Does the second script work if you run it by itself? It also looks like you have two outputs from your first script, not just one. Are they both being set properly?

Comment: Maybe you could add the complete error code to the question. The screenshot does not help on that.

Comment: Please always present code as text rather than pictures so that it can be searched for and copy/pasted for testing.  Error messages should also be as text so that they can be searched for too.

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues.
First, it doesn't look like you are actually setting the output parameter.

In the first script, you have:

```
folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

and then later:

```
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0,'pom')
```

That last line essentially tries to assign 'pom' to the same parameter that you got your `folder` variable from. I don't think that actually does anything, since your first parameter appears to be an input parameter.
And, unless I'm missing something, or you didn't post all of the code, I don't see anything that would have set an output parameter to a date value (unless that's what 'pom' means).

Second, even if the output parameter was being set properly, you wouldn't get the behavior that you wanted.
The entire script will run, then it will pass the values of the parameters into the next script. Since you are setting those values in a for loop, only the last value will actually get passed.
It looks like you are trying to make your own model iterator, but I don't think that's possible in this fashion.